# PHP script to create index file

Tags: joomla

I need a php script that will create or copy from a path a blank index.html file for each folder that doesn't have one.
If some one has one please share.
Thanks
H

Comment: you have a dedicated place for joomla question at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs here just as much as in joomla.stackexchange.com, it is not joomla-specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your blank index.html - file and place it below your www- folder. Then, standing in the same place below your www- folder, try something like this:

```
find www -type d -exec cp -n index.html {}/index.html \;
```

...where www is your www-folder. This should copy the index.html - file to all folders below the www-folder, including the www-folder itself. The copy `-n` flag ensures existing index.html - files are not overwritten.

To make this into a php-script, you could just wrap it in a exec, like:

```
<?php
$path = 'path/to/www'; // www-folder
$index = 'path/to/index.html';
exec('find '.$path.' -type d -exec cp -n '.$index.' {}/index.html \;');
```

Place the code above in a php-file.

This solution is not platform independant, but will work on most flavours of *nix and mac.